# How can I move emails from one Hotmail account to another?

Tags: outlook.com

I want to switch between two Hotmail (outlook.com) accounts and move all my stored emails to the new account.

Perhaps this was a bit wishful thinking but I can't even seem to forward multiple emails at once?

So I'm happy with either:

- Moving emails from one Live account to another
- Forwarding multiple emails at once instead of individually
- Export/Import of emails

Comment: If Hotmail supports IMAP, you can use a program like thunderbird or windows live mail and literally drag and drop messages around, I believe.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/hotmail/send-receive-email-from-mail-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded external mail software (Outlook) where I could easily connect to both my email addresses and move email from one account to the other by drag & dropping the folders/emails.